# How to pre-render a terminal buffer before displaying it in a popup

Tags: vimscript, terminal, popup

I am currently trying to write my first plugin. So this is my first attempt at vimscript. I want to display the output of a shell command in a popup window.

This can easily achieved with:

```
command Cat call CatCurFile()

function! CatCurFile()
    let buf = term_start(['cat', @%], #{hidden: 1})
    let winid = popup_create(buf, #{minwidth: 120, minheight: 70})
endfunction
```

The popup window is built up from top to bottom, which is not pretty. I would like the have the whole terminal buffer pre-rendered somehow, so that it instantly displays everything.

cat is just an example here. The actual application is a bit slower unfortunately.

I have tried

```
command Cat call CatCurFile()

function! CatCurFile()
    let buf = term_start(['cat', @%], #{hidden: 1})
    let winid = popup_create(buf, #{hidden: 1, minwidth: 120, minheight: 70})
    popup_show(winid)
endfunction
```

but the popup is not showing. Instead an error saying `menu not found` is displayed. Is the id not passed right?

Comment: You have to write `:call popup_show(winid)` to call a function (unless you're using vim9script) (the colon is optional in scripts). Also see the `"term_finish": "open"` option on `term_start()`

Comment: Works, but it is not built up faster. Guess I can sleep in between although that is ugly

Comment: Nothing vim can do will make the external command finish faster… I’m not sure exactly what the issue is? With `term_finish` as open, the window doesn’t even open until the command is finished, so all the output is there.

Comment: I am trying to make a vim plugin for glow, since the https://github.com/ellisonleao/glow.nvim does not have Vim support. The nvim version loads instantly and my version is pretty slow. Maybe there is a better way than using the terminal as popup

Comment: Really weird, I just added a border and now it loads faster...